# LAMP AuthType Not set error in Debian

Tags: php, linux, debian, lamp

So this should be basic, but I'm running into issues while setting up LAMP in Debian. I have followed the instructions at https://wiki.debian.org/LaMp to a T, but when I go to test php with a simple phpinfo script, I am getting an internal server error.

I checked the apache error log and I am getting "configuration error: couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!"

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing this should fix your problem. You're using Apache 2.4 directives on Apache 2.2.

```
Require all granted
```